# Asynchronous POST to server

Tags: objective-c, post, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

The goal is to do a simple username/password authentication by querying a database. Until the connection is working decently my php destination file simply has following code:

```
echo "Posted: " . $_POST['email'];
```

The code to do this synchronously is this:

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@", self.email.text, ..]; // .. simplified keychainItem
NSData *postEncoded = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postEncoded length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a11_web02/improver/app/testPost"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postEncoded];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *encodedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:encodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data? %@",data);
```

The correct value is shown as an echo. But when trying to do this asynchronously, I get following php error: "Undefined index: email".
I try to start the asynchronous request with this line:

```
[[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] start];
```

Then, I have the delegate method connection:didReceiveResponse, but there I cannot seem to get the data out... Or do I need another delegate method? Also, how 'safe' is it to check the result of your query by using just an echo (do I need/want a stream maybe?) ??

Tia

**EDIT**

Problem related to the server, not to objective-C code. Asked a new question to reach the correct audience: [$_POST remaining empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071149/post-remaining-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ott is on the right track, I'll try to clarify.

1. You don't need `start` as he says. It's benign as the connection will start automatically.
2. `initWithRequest:delegate` and `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` are equivalent except for the retain state of the new `connection` object.
3. The real problem is b/c you are using `connectionWithRequest:delegate` the returned connection is autoreleased at the end of the run loop and you are not retaining it in a property. Therefore, the connection never starts.

The solution is to add a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection` to your class and set this property to the connection returned from `connection:withRequest:`

You then release the connection in the completion methods `connection:didFinishLoading` and `connection:didFailWithError:`.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying. Added the @property and retained the NSURLConnection with connectionWithRequest:delegate:

However, still getting PHP error "Undefined index: email"

Comment: well, that's the response from your server so you need to debug it from there. whether you do the request synchronously or asynchronously doesn't matter. look at what data you are posting and make sure it's what the server requires. my answer had to do with proper use of NSURLConnection.

Comment: True.

It seems my $_POST variable remains empty. Using print_r($_POST) to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

The `start` is wrong here. Simply use

```
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

with `NSURLConnection *connection;` defined. See the class reference for `connectionWithRequest`. `start` is to be used with `initWithRequest:delegate:`.

Comment: Okay, so connectionWithRequest:delegate: begins to load the data for the URL request, no start needed.
Still getting "Undefined index: email" as a PHP error back, this must mean that the POST variables aren't being found...