# $_POST remaining empty

Tags: php, post, httprequest, server-side

This question came as a result out of: [Asynchronous POST to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044144/asynchronous-post-to-server). To reach people with the correct knowledge (it has to do with the server instead of the objective-C code) I created a new question.

I'm trying to POST to a server from within objective-C. When debugging on the server however, I noticed that the $_POST variable remains empty. I think (really not sure) it has to do with one of these things:

- a redirect that I am not aware of, which empties the $_POST variable
- print of $_SERVER contains this: [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET ???

The original url I am using in my code is: http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php
Printing the $_SERVER variable results in this:

```
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */* 
[HTTP_REFERER] => http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a11_web02/ 
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => nl-BE 
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0) 
[HTTP_UA_CPU] => AMD64 
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate 
[HTTP_HOST] => eng.studev.groept.be 
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive 
[PATH] => C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\RAC4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\svn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\php;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\ 
[SystemRoot] => C:\Windows 
[COMSPEC] => C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe 
[PATHEXT] => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC 
[WINDIR] => C:\Windows 
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o SVN/1.6.13 PHP/5.3.3 
[SERVER_NAME] => eng.studev.groept.be 
[SERVER_ADDR] => 193.190.255.36 [SERVER_PORT] => 80 
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 193.190.253.160 
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => D:/webroot/eng 
[SERVER_ADMIN] => //censored
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => D:/webroot/eng/web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php 
[REMOTE_PORT] => 49187 
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET 
[QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] => /web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php 
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php 
[PHP_SELF] => /web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php 
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1320869183
```

Anyone getting wiser out of this?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Code to generate the POST request:

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@", self.email.text, self.password.text];    
NSData *postEncoded = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postEncoded length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postEncoded];

// asynchronous request
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Yes, this is a GET request, so $_POST is empty. So what?

Comment: How can it be a GET request if I have this line in my code: [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; ? Obviously, something is wrong.. :)

Comment: Can you show your current code setting up the POST request?

Comment: Edited question with code to set up POST request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET`

You didn't post anything.

Comment: I have this line in my code: [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; and my HTTPBody contains the POST variables..

Comment: @mmvie You should post a new question about the code you're writing then and find out why it doesn't make the correct request.